# Rbind not returning expected result

Tags: r, dataframe, append, subset, rbind

I'd like to ask a question about R and subset.

The condition is I have 2 datasets, with different contents but the same header.
The second dataset is the continuation from the first dataset.

Example:

Dataset A(first dataset)

```
ID   Name   Month
 1    AAA       1
 1    AAA       2
 1    AAA       3
 2    BBB       1
 2    BBB       2
```

Dataset B(second dataset)

```
ID   Name   Month
 1    AAA       4
 1    AAA       5
 2    BBB       3
 2    BBB       4
```

After `rbind`, the second dataset is not appending with the first dataset.

Expected Result is:

Dataset C

```
ID   Name   Month  
 1    AAA       1  
 1    AAA       2  
 1    AAA       3  
 1    AAA       4  
 1    AAA       5    
 2    BBB       1  
 2    BBB       2 
 2    BBB       3 
 2    BBB       4
```

So I try to subset the second dataset to check if there are any missing observations.

```
test <- subset(B, B$id == 1)
```

The code above is not resulting anything (0 obs).
But if I changed it into dataset `A`, it will generate 3 obs.

The type from both datasets are the same, I changed it manually.

As for the `rbind` code is:

```
C <- rbind.data.frame(A, B)
```

Does anybody ever experiencing the same problem?

Comment: `rbind` is producing expected output i.e. Dataset C

Comment: R is case sensitive. It should be `test <- subset(B, B$ID == 1)`.

Comment: Do you get an error after rbind, or something else? Could you give str(A) and str(B)?

Comment: Pardon my typo, yes I already tried to use B$ID but still not producing anything. On the rbind, I didn't get any error, but it just not appending the 2 datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I already found the answer.
Apparently, there are whitespaces behind the ID in dataset 2.
And I think because of the length difference, the rbind fuction is not working well.